# How can I get a query with a conditional in a third relation?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

Im using Laravel 7 and to get an array like this [Array image spect result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbGIP.png)

And im working with Eloquent. This is my code for that array

```
**return EvaluateTeacherQuestion::with('evaluate_teacher_possibles_answers')->get();**
```

And this is my function evaluate_teacher_possibles_answers to make the relationship

```
public function evaluate_teacher_possibles_answers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(EvaluateTeacherPossibilites::class)->withCount('evaluate_teacher_answers')->with('evaluate_teacher_answers');
}
```

And to get the third condition use this

```
public function evaluate_teacher_answers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(EvaluateTeacherAnswer::class, 'evaluate_teacher_possible_id');
}
```

The problem is in the table evaluate_teacher_answers, I need get only this that if a condition (teacher_id = $teacher) is right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:
remove `with('evaluate_teacher_answers')` from `evaluate_teacher_possibles_answers` relation:

```
public function evaluate_teacher_possibles_answers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(EvaluateTeacherPossibilities::class)->withCount('evaluate_teacher_answers')->;
}
```

then load that relation with your condition:

```
 $value = EvaluateTeacherQuestion::with(['evaluate_teacher_possibles_answers'=>function($query)use($teacher_id)
        {
            $query->with(['evaluate_teacher_answers'=>function($query)use($teacher_id){
                $query = $query->where('evaluate_teacher_answers.teacher_id',$teacher_id);
            }]);
        }])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add the `whereHas` condition a subquery is added.
Eg:

```
EvaluateTeacherQuestion::with('evaluate_teacher_possibles_answers')->whereHas('evaluate_teacher_possibles_answers',function($query){
         $query->where('column','operation','value');
    })->get();
```

With this way, will included relation in model and will execute conditions on closure from related model